# C++ member initialization VS inherited constructor initialization

Tags: c++, inheritance

I know that one way to initiate members of a class is to write the following:

```
class base {
 int id;
 public:
 base(int id): id(id){}
};
```

But what if I mix this syntax with `constructor initialization of a derived class`:

```
class base {
 int id;
 public:
 base(int id): id(id){}
};

class dri : public base {
 int base;
 public:
 dri(int id): base(id){}
};
```

In the example above under the `derived` class, is `base(id){}` referring to `int base` or `class base`? I assume it is referring to `int base` since is' not compiling. How can I make it refer to `class base`?

Edit:

Second question, let's say you look at a random C++ code which looks like this:

```
class base {
 int id;
 public:
 base(int id): id(id){}
};
```

How can you tell if `id(id){}` is initializing a local variable or initializing another classes constructor?

Comment: Don't reuse the identifier `base` is the simplest advice.

Comment: Use a clear naming convention to differentiate between variables and class names (and anything else), and the problem will solve itself.

Comment: Well I can rephrase the question by asking "if you just look at this class, how can you tell if `base(id){}` is initializing a local variable, or initializing a constructor?

Comment: *How can you tell if* -- By going to the C++ standard document, reading the paragraph and understand it -- or you can forego all this effort and just write coherent code.

Comment: In question #2 `class base {` there is no other class.

Comment: @drescherjm so that's the only way? basically the syntax for initializing a derived class an initialing a variable is the same in c++? seems like a poor design

Comment: Well, you would do well renaming your local variables instead of calling all of them `id`or `base`, it will be clearly. Now, answering your question, it works in this way: The compiler create an instance of `base` before a new instance of `dir`. So, in this case, the invocations would be as: `int x = 23; dir c = new dri(x);` which creates a new instance of base: `new base(23) : id(23){}` and returns to complete the creation of `dri` instance, setting the local variable `base` the value of `x`.

Comment: ***seems like a poor design*** I would say the poor design was by the person writing code like this. Write your code to be readable. This is one of the most important parts of being a programmer. Someone will have to read it (maybe that person is you two years from now).

Comment: @drescherjm calm down, i'm just trying to learn this language and it's syntax and playing around with the compiler.

Comment: Having a naming convention could keep you out of this situation. I have never found myself in this situation that you describe and I have written more than 1 million lines of c++ code professionally.

Comment: A base class is just another variable. Other than specifying it by the name of the class rather than the name of an instance there's no need for a different set of rules. What you've run up against is no different from `int string; string test;` by the time the compiler reaches `string test`, the meaning of `string` has been changed by the programmer. There is no solution for this other than don't do it. I can see a case for a "Dude WTF?!?!" type warning message, but in general redefining an identifier is acceptable behaviour.

Comment: @JorgeOmarMedra the answer section is below ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't reuse the identifier `base` is the simplest advice.

More complex would be use scope resolution:

```
dri(int id): ::base(id){}
              ^
              use base from the global namespace
```

## Post question edit answer:

The most recently defined use of an identifier will be used over definitions in outer scopes unless an outer scope is explicitly specified. There is no good way to tell which you will get without acting like the compiler and building a graph of what identifiers are defined and where and performing the resolution yourself.

What you've run up against is exactly the same as

```
int string; 
string test;
```

by the time the compiler reaches `string test`, the meaning of `string` has been changed by the programmer from a type to a variable of type `int`. There is no solution for this other than don't do it.

This brings us back to the opening point: Don't reuse identifiers in encompassed scopes without good reason. Someone will screw it up.

Comment: Thank you, I added a second question

Comment: ***I added a second question*** `StackOverflow` is normally supposed to be 1 question per question.

Comment: so the syntax for initializing a derived class an initialing a variable is the same in c++?

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean there, Joe. The syntax for initializing a *base* class is the same. Your problem here is with scope resolution.

Comment: There is noting different to tell the compiler we are initializing the base class versus some member variable.